# Android Service Error: android.app.ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException

Tags: android, foreground

I want to create a Service in Android to start a long activity but it crashes with the following message shown:

> android.app.ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{2134ac4 u0 com.example.foregroundservice/.MyForegroundService}
> at android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException(ActivityThread.java:1923)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2700(ActivityThread.java:247)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2148)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

Here is my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    if (!foregroundServiceRunning())
    {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyForegroundService.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }

}

public void getTimeButtonPressed(View v)
{
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(MyForegroundService.getsystemtime());
}

public boolean foregroundServiceRunning()
{
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service: activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
    {
        if(MyForegroundService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And it is the foreground service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    new Thread(
            new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Log.e("Service", "Service is running...");
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

    ).start();

    final String CHANNELID ="Foreground Service ID";
    NotificationChannel channel = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNELID, CHANNELID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        getSystemService(NotificationManager.class).createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNELID)
                .setContentText("Service is running...")
                .setContentTitle("Service enabled")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    }
    startForeground(1001, notification.build());
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public static String getsystemtime()
{
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ss:mm:hh dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
    return simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
}
```

What I shall I do to fix the problem?

**Edit**

I add a new line to the onStartCommand. A strange thing happens: it runs smoothly on my emmulator but it crashes immediately when running on my phone (redmi 10) with the following message shown:

[error message1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TCPj.jpg)
[error message2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOSqn.jpg)

Comment: Post the stack trace as code in the question rather than a link to a url.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Service.onStartCommand()` you create a `Notification`, but you never use it. You need to call `startForeground()` and pass your `Notification`. If the `Activity` calls `startForegroundService()` then Android expects that the `Service` will call `startForeground()` inside `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I add one more line to the onStartCommand. It runs smoothly on emmulator but it crashes immediately on my phone. What shall I do?

Comment: You need to declare the foreground service type in your manifest. See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required

Answer (score 0):

Android 14 requires that foreground services are given a service type. The error message in the links are pointing out that you haven't declared one.

You can find more information baout that here : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required